# How to get Jenkins Jobs log into Spinnaker UI

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I have Spinnaker connected to Jenkins and I am able to trigger Jenkins jobs. Spinnaker only shows a url link to Jenkins jobs :

**Jenkins Stage Configuration**

**Master** prod

**Job** SRE/job/Puppet_Run

**Build** [#7](https://myjenkins/job/Ansible/job/Ansible_ex1/24/)

I want to be able to see the output from Jenkins jobs directly in spinnaker UI 
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do that:

1. Put your execution log into property file and expose as artifact in Jenkins Job - https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/#property-files
2. Add Webhook stage and get output using GET http://jenkins.local/job/JOB_NAME/1/consoleText